# Check if model belongs to other model

Tags: laravel, model

In my application, I have users that are connected to businesses. These businesses have job offers. When a user wants to edit a business' job offer, the url will be like **/business/foo/job/bar**. When I change the business variable to the name of a different one, like this: **/business/*other-business*/job/bar** I still get the job called bar even though it does not belong to the business. I tried to use gates to check if the job offers belong to the business but it didn't work. Below is the code for the edit function which shows the edit page.

```
public function edit(Business $business, Job $job)
{
    return view('dashboard.business.jobs.edit', [
        'business' => $business,
        'job' => $job,
    ]);
}
```

I can add the following code to all the functions but it is not very pretty

```
if($business->id !== $job->business->id) { return abort(404); }
```

I was wondering if there is a better solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can choose between

```php
if($business->jobs->contains($job->id)) return redirect()->to("somewhere");
```

or

```php
if($job->business->is($business)) return redirect()->to("somewhere");
```

The second one is more efficient because you have to retrive from the database just one record to check if they are correlated, the business record, where the first one instead you have to retrive all the jobs of that business.
Those solution in my opinion are actually very clear, you can literally read them and understand what you are doing.

Also if you want just one line of code, you can do this:

```php
public function edit(Business $business, Job $job)
{
    return 
        $job->business->is($business) 
            ? 
                view('dashboard.business.jobs.edit', [
                     'business' => $business,
                     'job' => $job,
                ])
            :
                return redirect()->to("somewhere");
}
```

Comment: That will work, indeed. But I also have functions like store and destroy. Using this solution it means that I have to add an if statement to all these functions. I was hoping for a solution whereby I did not have to use if statements in every function.

Comment: well somewhere you have to check this, or here or on the route, and also on there route there will be some code repeated... check somewhere if you can customize Route Model Binding , but i don't think so